# Дана матрица размером x, y. Данный код подсчитывает сумму чисел столбцов матрицы. Как отобразить эти суммы в порядке возрастания

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

def matrix():

    x = int(input("Введите количество строк матрицы: "))
    y = int(input("Введите количество столбцов матрицы: "))
    massyv = []
    for i in range (x):
        massyv.append([])
        for j in range(y):
            massyv[i].append(random.randint(0,10))
        print("Матрица: ")
    for u in range(x):
        print(massyv[u])
    for q in range(y):
        suma = 0
        for w in range(x):
            suma += massyv[w] [q]
        print("%3d"%suma, end=" ")

matrix()
```

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что Вам просто нужно отсортировать полученный список с помощью метода `sort`.

Но мне не удалось разобраться в Вашем коде, поэтому я решил сделать свою реализацию:

```py
import random


def main():
    n = int(input('Введите количество строк матрицы: '))
    m = int(input('Введите количество столбцов матрицы: '))

    # Создание матрицы (list comprehension)
    matrix = [[random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]
    print('Матрица:', *matrix, sep='\n', end='\n\n')

    column_sums = []                    # Суммы столбцов
    for j in range(m):                  # Итерация по индексу (j) столбца
        column_sum = 0                  # Сумма столбца

        for i in range(n):              # Итерация по индексу (i) строки
            column_sum += matrix[i][j]
        column_sums.append(column_sum)

    column_sums.sort()                  # Сортировка
    print('Суммы столбцов в порядке возрастания:', column_sums, sep='\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Возможный `stdout` (при `n = 3; m = 4`):*

```py
Матрица:
[9, 3, 1, 3]
[5, 7, 9, 0]
[0, 3, 0, 4]

Суммы столбцов в порядке возрастания:
[7, 10, 13, 14]
```